# Unable to install MultiBit 64bit version

Tags: multibit, error, installation

How do I install the 64 bit version of MultiBit? I downloaded the MultiBit client that is supposed to be compatible with 32 bit & 64 bit but when I run the program it give an error message that says that the program is incompatible with the current version of Windows that it is being run under. How do I get the MultiBit client to run in 64 bit?

Comment: Hi Thom, and welcome to the Bitcoin StackExchange community! You'd get a much better answer if you took a screenshot of the error message, and posted it here. Remember, you can edit your question after posting it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by the multibit.exe executable not being able to find the 64 bit version of Java.
There is some discussion about it on the MultiBit issues database here:
https://github.com/jim618/multibit/issues/376

tl;dr If you install the 32 bit bit Oracle Java runtime MultiBit should find and use that.

Comment: I did find out what happened. My system booted into another desktop account so once I figured that out I removed that program. The original was still there so I backed up the wallet. What I need to know now is how to transfer from one bitcoing wallet address within the same wallet